# Make Select from table depending of existence in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Guys I want to Select from table `articles` depending if `code` is in table called `inStock` . So for example if I have in column `code` in table `inStock` 224 I need to Select * FROM `articles` having that code and for every item same. Any help?

This is table `inStock`

[image]

And this is table `articles`

[image]

Comment: Have you made any attempt yet?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No i am just starting with that, but having no good knowledge in mysql I had no idea how to do this otherwise I'd put some code attempt

Comment: For next time, you need to do some proper research and make some attempts before asking. SO isn't a free coding service. This time, you were lucky to get answers. Questions like this (with no attempts) are too broad and are usually down voted and closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following query: with inner join you can get this as code need to present in both table, hopefully you'll get your desired ans

```
select a.id,a.code,a.name,a.description,a.amount,a.color,b.price
from articles a inner join instock b
on a.code=b.code
```

Comment: tablename* will give you all columns from that table, check my ans

Comment: I also need price from `inStock` ?

Comment: just run my query, you'll get all of your desired columns

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, in my answer I didn't put * :), I select all individual columns

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  no issues, it's ok

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT articles.*, inStock.Price
FROM articles INNER JOIN inStock ON articles.code = inStock.code
```

INNER JOIN will return the records that are present in both the tables based on the columns that you are joining

Comment: What about other collumns from `articles` ?

Comment: asterisk(*) will return all the columns from articles

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query:

```
SELECT `A`.*, `S`.`price` 
FROM inStock S 
JOIN articles A 
ON (`S`.`code` = `A`.`code`);
```

Here you have a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/293321/1) for this: